Await tasks with continue with c#
I am trying to iterate all the results and get from cache additional value and add it to concurrent dictionary. I am using continue with option but that is not ensuring the continue with tasks are completed
  private async Task<List<Task>> PopulateValuesFromCacheToDictionaryTasks(
    List<Search> searchResults)
    {
        List<Task> taskList = new();
        foreach (var result in searchResults)
        {
            var currentId = result.Id;
           var parentTask = _appCache.GetAsync(currentId ).ContinueWith(
                x =>
            {

                if (_appDictionary.TryAdd(currentId , x.Result))
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Successfully added entry for {currentId } in dictionary");
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogError($"Unable to add entry {currentId } in dictionary");
                }
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
            taskList .Add(parentTask);
        }

        return taskList ;

    }

//In the calling code 
 


var listOfCacheFetchTasks = 
  PopulateValuesFromCacheToDictionaryTasks(searchResults);
 await Task.WhenAll(listOfCacheFetchTasks );

// further processing based on the dictionary added values


This is not ensuring the continue with code (ie) adding to dictionary is completed
Tried adding parent and child task individually and awaiting both that is also not working

You may have unsafe concurrent access to that list

Don't. Just await and insert. I don't see any benefit in doing it  like this. Also, consider not using interpolated strings as log message templates (which is unrelated, though).

Why not just use await? There's no benefit to this code but it does make it a lot easier to introduce errors. Right now, unless _appDictionary is a ConcurrentDictionary, this code will cause errors. If you want to make multiple concurrent calls you can extract the await GetAsync()/_appDictionary.TryAdd code into a separate method, even local method, and eg use .Select to fire off all tasks at once. Or you can use Parallel.ForEachAsync. In all cases _appDictionary will have to be a concurrent collection

I am using concurrent dictionary also I need to know the value of the previous task and insert that in dictionary in this case I need to get the key from cache and insert the value retrieved from cache for the key in the concurrent dictionary

Also mind that you probably are DoS-attacking your own cache. Doing stuff in parallel / concurrently does not magically always improve throughput. Actually, it might clog up your system instead. Start with the dumbest possible implementation that is readable and does what you expect. It might just happen to be good enough.

@Geetha That doesn't explain why ContinueWith is used. Besides, you should check for existence before making the expensive GetAsync call.

If items does not exist in cache I have fall back code to handle for those items. The reason I used continue with is to iterate all result item ,get from cache the value for the item and store both the key and value in dictionary. The add to dictionary should be done only if the get from cache is successful and I want to run all the cache get in parallel for all the search results

"I want to run all the cache get in parallel " - why, though? I'd expect a lot of collisions unless that cache is specifically and particularly implemented to support concurrent access lock-free. Why not implement a first attempt that ... works? Then take measurements and see if you need to make it faster? You can always increase complexity later on.

There's no benefit to ContinueWith here. It's unclear why the code is so complicated. The simplest way to asynchronously check a cache and update a local copy would be to use Parallel.ForEachAsync. By default Parallel.ForEachAsync uses as many worker tasks as there are CPU cores to process the data.
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(searchResults,async (result,token)=>{
    var currentId=result.Id;
    //No need to request an already loaded value
    if(_appDictionary.ContainsKey(currentId));
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Dictionary already contains {currentId }",currentId);
    }
    else
    {
        var value=await _appCache.GetAsync(currentId);
        //Perhaps `searchResults` contained duplicates?
        if (_appDictionary.TryAdd(currentId , value))
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Successfully added entry for {currentId } in dictionary",currentId);
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogError("Already loaded {currentId } in dictionary",currentId);
        }
    }
});

The possibility of duplicates can be removed if we use eg searchResults.Select(x=>x.Id).Disctinct(). Even better, .Where can be used to remove already cached IDs:
var searchIds=searchResults.Select(x=>x.Id)
                           .Disctinct()
                           .Where(id=>!_appDictionary.ContainsKey(id))
                           .ToList();

await Parallel.ForEachAsync(searchIds,async (currentId,token)=>{
    var value=await _appCache.GetAsync(currentId);

    if (_appDictionary.TryAdd(currentId , value))
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Successfully added entry for {currentId } in dictionary",currentId);
    }
    else
    {
        _logger.LogError("Already loaded {currentId } in dictionary",currentId);
    }
});

